# Applying Gradient on UIView not getting expected result

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, cagradientlayer

I just simply want to apply Gradient with 2 UIColors that's why I written below code.

```
class Constants: NSObject {
    class func applyGradient(localView:UIView, color1:UIColor, color2:UIColor) {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = localView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [color1.CGColor, color2.CGColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 1)
        localView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
        localView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

and applying via below code in UIViewController's viewDidLoad.

```
Constants.applyGradient(viewContactDetail, color1: gradientColor1, color2: gradientColor2)
Constants.applyGradient(viewDiscountDetail, color1: gradientColor1, color2: gradientColor2)
Constants.applyGradient(viewTermsCondDetail, color1: gradientColor1, color2: gradientColor2)
Constants.applyGradient(viewDiscountAvailDetail, color1: gradientColor1, color2: gradientColor2)
```

And here is the result what I'm getting

[image]

You can see, Gradient isn't apply on specific view properly.

I'm not getting what is wrong with my code.

**EDIT:**
Here is the hierarchical view.
[image]

Comment: You'r code is proper. Please try it with basic UIColor.

Comment: @Mrugesh Tank check my answer

Comment: @Mrugesh Tank you want two colors in gradient for particular view?

Comment: @AnkitaShah, I'm using Basic UIcolor, like gradientColor1 have white color and gradientColor2 have some RGB color which looks like grey

Comment: I just copied you'r code in one of my project and it's working properly

Comment: My code is working properly in another project, but not in this.

Comment: @MrugeshTank Check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Try this....hope its helpful for you**

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.frame = self.shadowview.bounds

    let colorTop = UIColor.green.cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor.black.cgColor

    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]


    self.shadowview.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

[image]

Comment: So, I just need to add .locations property??

Comment: @MrugeshTank u get solution?

Comment: exactly which type of gradient layer u want?

Comment: gradient layer is proper how I want but, it's height is not proper, Cause I have each view with border . You can see in screenshot where borders are there and where gradient layer ends.

Comment: hey @MrugeshTank http://prntscr.com/cv9bm5  i have created  view like this please see and tell me, i will give you demo

Comment: Yes @seggy, That is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code too in which you can give frame of gradient layer and give color too

```
let gradient1 = CAGradientLayer()
gradient1.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size:  CGSize (width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: btn_cancel.frame.size.height))
gradient1.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.init(red: 237.0/255.0, green: 237.0/255.0, blue: 237.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor]
print(gradient1.frame)
```

just Add that layer to the view

```
 "YOUR VIEW".layer.addSublayer(gradient1)
```

In [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upAZy.png) You can see I added gradient layer to button, So you can do as same to add in your view or any other control

Answer (score 0):

Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the frame worked for me. If in your case if don't want to call this try using `willDisplayCell` by setting a bool which will be applied for the first time only and when your frames are ready.